# Ansible module for symlinks

Tags: symbolic-link, ansible

Is there a [standard Ansible module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_all_modules.html) for manipulating symbolic links (a wrapper of `mklink`)?

- [`file`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html) does that only for Linux
- [`win_file`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_file_module.html#synopsis) windows counterpart omits such functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You will need to use:

```
win_command: cmd.exe /k mklink
```

If you think a symlink feature would be useful you could make it yourself and submit a PR, the powershell code for win_file is here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/windows/win_file.ps1

Or make a proposal here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/new?template=feature_request.md

Comment: The link to https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/windows/win_file.ps1 is 404.